# Loading new content to an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript variable with some HTML content.

I want to replace the current html page with this new HTML content.

**Example**: `var html = '<html> <p> new content </p> </html>'`

I want to load the content of variable into my HTML.

How would I go about doing so?

Comment: document.getElementById('yourID').innerHTML = html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var html = "<p>Hi</p>";
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Answer (score 2):

To load new content use:-

```
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```